# How to add a value after being logged in?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working in an android studio project and I have a login activity,I created database using `SharedPreferences` and `SQLite`;I have created a table which has columns id,email,password,check_in,check_out.
I made it possible to login after I register a user;but I do not know how to insert a data in check_in cell of logged user.
So my problem is that how to make possible to add the time of check_in in table in database after logged in?
And how I can the see the table created using `SQLite`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("check_in", value);
contentValues.put("check_out", value);


// this will insert if record is new, update otherwise
db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I made it possible to login after I register a user;but I do not know
>   how to insert a data in check_in cell of logged user.

You would use the SQLiteDatabase's `update` method something along the lines of :-

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("check_in",System.currentTimeMillis());
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.update("your_table_name",cv,"email=? AND user=?",new String[]{email,user});
```

> And how I can the see the table created using SQLite?

You can

- install a product that provides this ability,
- copy the database via adb or tools that utilise adb, so that a product that can look at SQLite databases can access the copied file,
- extract a cursor from the table and then use this as the source for displaying the data e.g you could use something like

:-

```
SQLiteDatabae db = this.getWriteableDatabase();
Cursor csr = db.query("your_table_name",null,null,null,null,null,null);
Databaseutils.dumpCursor(csr);
csr.close();
```